# Enhance images for colorblind people

Tags: java, image, accessibility, color-blindness

I'm looking for an easy to use Java library that provides some standard methods for enhancing existing images for colorblind people. I found some [browser plugins](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colorblindext/) and web sites that do these enhancements, but I found no corresponding Java library. Is there such a library, and if not, is there at least a good source of information how I can implement this functionality on my own?

Comment: You might start by looking at [Dan Kaminsky's work](http://dankaminsky.com/2010/12/15/dankam/) or even contacting him directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any color blind specific libraries but I did come across a very interesting document which explains how a Mozilla color blind add on was built. The addon uses the Java Advance Imaging (JAI) library to improve the readability. Below are the links to the document:

http://www.faer.ac.in/motorola/pdf/04_Mozilla%20Firefox%20Extension.pdf

Edit: the document says the code for the extension is open source.